# How to check if a xml file contains consecutive nodes?

Tags: c#, xml

I have some xml file that look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="jats-html.xsl"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD with OASIS Tables v1.0 20120330//EN" "JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1.dtd">-->
<article article-type="proceedings" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:oasis="http://www.niso.org/standards/z39-96/ns/oasis-exchange/table">
<front>
<journal-meta>
<journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id" />
<journal-title-group>
<journal-title>Eleventh &#x0026; Tenth International Conference on Correlation Optics</journal-title>
</journal-title-group>
<issn pub-type="epub">0277-786X</issn>
<publisher>
<publisher-name>Springer</publisher-name>
</publisher>
</journal-meta>
<fig-count count="0" />
<table-count count="0" />
<equation-count count="0" />
</front>
<body>
<sec id="s1">
<label>a.</label>
<title>INTRODUCTION</title>
<p>One of approaches of solving<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref8">[8]</xref> the problem <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref1">[1]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref5">[2]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref6">[6]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref7">[6]</xref> of light propagation in scattering media is the method of Monte Carlo statistical simulation<sup><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c1">1</xref>–<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c5">5</xref></sup>. It is a set of techniques that allow us to find the necessary solutions by repetitive random sampling. Estimates of the unknown quantities are statistical means.</p>
<p>For the case of radiation transport in scattering <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref6">6</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref8">8</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref9">9</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref10">10</xref> medium Monte Carlo method consists in repeated calculation of the trajectory <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref7">6</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref7">7</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref8">8</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref9">[9]</xref> of a photon in a medium based on defined environment parameters. Application of Monte Carlo method is based on the use of macroscopic optical properties of the medium which are considered homogeneous within small volumes of tissue. Models that are based on this method can be divided into two types: models that take into account the polarization of the radiation, and models that ignore it.</p>
<p>Simulation that is based on the previous models usually discards the details of the radiation energy distribution within a single scattering particle. This disadvantage can be ruled out (in the case of scattering particles whose size exceeds the wavelength) by using another method - reverse ray tracing. This method is like the one mentioned before on is based on passing a large number of photons through a medium that is simulated. The difference is that now each scattering particle has a certain geometric topology and scattering is now calculated using the Fresnel equations. The disadvantage of this method is that it can give reliable results only if the particle size is much greater than the wavelength (at least an order of magnitude).</p>
</sec>
</body>
</article>
```

in which there are link nodes in the form `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref...">...</xref>`. How can I find if there are 3 or more consecutive link nodes (separated by **a comma and a space** or simply **space** in the file and output them to a txt file.

I can do a regex search like `(?:<xref type="bibr" rid="ref\d+">\[\d+\]</xref>\s*,\s*){2,}<xref type="bibr" rid="ref\d+">\[\d+\]</xref>` which will find 3 or more link nodes separated by a ",SPACE" or "SPACE" but they are not necessarily bound to have consecutive id's. How do I do this?

Comment: I have updated the code. It should be pass all your test cases now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So In order to comply with your requirements I hereby present to you my solution for your problem. I haven't thoroughly tested the possibility of duplicates. i.e. where some refs might just be a subset of a former result. But it should be no problem to sort them out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    doc.Load("article.xml");

    //only selects <p>'s that already have 3 or more refs. No need to check paragraphs that don't even have enough refs
    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*[count(xref[@ref-type='bibr' and starts-with(@rid,'ref')])>2]");

    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    //Foreach <p>
    foreach (XmlNode x in nodes)
    {
        XmlNodeList xrefs = x.SelectNodes(".//xref[@ref-type='bibr' and starts-with(@rid,'ref')]");
        List<StartEnd> startEndOfEachTag = new List<StartEnd>(); // we mark the start and end of each ref.
        string temp = x.OuterXml; //the paragraph we're checking

        //finds start and end of each tag xref tag
        foreach (XmlNode xN in xrefs){ //We find the start and end of each paragraph
            StartEnd se = new StartEnd(temp.IndexOf(xN.OuterXml), temp.IndexOf(xN.OuterXml) + xN.OuterXml.Length);
            startEndOfEachTag.Add(se);  
        }

        /* This comment shows the regex command used and how we build the regular expression we are checking with.
        string regexTester = Regex.Escape("<xref ref-type=\"bibr\" rid=\"ref2\">2</xref>")+"([ ]|(, ))" + Regex.Escape("<xref ref-type=\"bibr\" rid=\"ref3\">3</xref>");
        Match matchTemp = Regex.Match("<xref ref-type=\"bibr\" rid=\"ref2\">2</xref> <xref ref-type=\"bibr\" rid=\"ref3\">3</xref>", regexTester);
        Console.WriteLine(matchTemp.Value);*/

        //we go through all the xrefs
        for (int i=0; i<xrefs.Count; i++)
        {
            int newIterator = i; //This iterator prevents us from creating duplicates.
            string regCompare = Regex.Escape(xrefs[i].OuterXml); // The start xref

            int count = 1; //we got one xref to start with we need at least 3
            string tempRes = ""; //the string we store the result in

            int consecutive = Int32.Parse(xrefs[i].Attributes["rid"].Value.Substring(3));

            for (int j=i+1; j<xrefs.Count; j++) //we check with the other xrefs to see if they follow immediately after.
            {
                if(consecutive == Int32.Parse(xrefs[j].Attributes["rid"].Value.Substring(3)) - 1)
                {
                    consecutive++;
                }
                else { break; }

                regCompare += "([ ]|(, ))" + Regex.Escape(xrefs[j].OuterXml); //we check that the the xref comes exactly after a space or a comma and space
                regCompare += "([ ]|(, ))" + Regex.Escape(xrefs[j].OuterXml); //we check that the the xref comes exactly after a space or a comma and space

                Match matchReg;

                try
                {
                    matchReg = Regex.Match(temp.Substring(startEndOfEachTag[i].start, startEndOfEachTag[j].end - startEndOfEachTag[i].start),
                        regCompare); //we get the result
                }
                catch
                {
                    i = j; // we failed and i should start from here now.
                    break;
                }

                if (matchReg.Success){
                    count++; //it was a success so we increment the number of xrefs we matched
                    tempRes = matchReg.Value; // we add it to out temporary result.
                    newIterator = j; //update where i should start from next time.
                }
                else {
                    i = j; // we failed and i should start from here now.
                    break;
                }
            }
            i = newIterator;
            if (count > 2)
            {
                results.Add(tempRes); 
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Results: ");
    foreach(string s in results)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(s+"\n");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**The missing class**

```
class StartEnd
{
    public int start=-1;
    public int end = -1;

    public StartEnd(int start, int end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `The type or namespace name 'StartEnd' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: Sorry my bad. I forget to include my class. Added it to the code.

Comment: The results are stored as strings in a List<string> called 'results'.

Comment: But your output is also showing `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref8">[8]</xref>` which do not have consecutive id?

Comment: They are consecutive notes. Each are only separated by a comma and a space. Really now they also have to have consecutive ID? I will update the code and get back to you.

Comment: I only wanted to get consecutive nodes with consecutive rid values, otherwise I could have just used a regex search pattern that I mentioned in my question to find these, finding consecutive nodes with consecutive rid values is the problem that I have..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159355/discussion-between-kent-kostelac-and-don-b).

Comment: it does no work if file has nodes in a range like `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref16">16</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref7">7</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref8">8</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref9">[9]</xref>` it throws an error `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.`

Comment: Update the xml you have with the case that doesn't work and I might take a look at it later.

Comment: I have updated the question with the sample xml that doesn't work...Also I had to comment the part which declares the `dtd` as it shows `System.IO.FileNotFoundException:` for the dtd and there is not a direct way of ignoring the dtd in `xmldocument` class like `doc.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore`

Comment: Are you sure that you updated the xml. Also I don't get any errors with:

<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref16">16</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref7">7</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref8">8</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref9">[9]</xref>.
I need to see the actual xml in order to determine what is wrong.

Comment: I do get an error `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.` in the line of code `Match matchReg = Regex.Match(temp.Substring(startEndOfEachTag[i].start, startEndOfEachTag[j].end - startEndOfEachTag[i].start),regCompare);`

Comment: And I am saying for the second time now. I can't replicate the error without the exact same xml file you're trying to parse.... How the hell do you expect me to debug?

Comment: I have updated the code a final time. I can't do much more than this without the original xml. IT is your job to figure it out. I have already shown you a method for getting the results you want. Now you must do the debugging. I have already done more than I should.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get rid of the dtd processing part..I used something like `XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.XmlResolver = null;
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
FileStream fs = new FileStream("sample.XML", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create(fs, settings);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);` instead of `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.Load("sample.XML"); ` I don't get any errors but I also don't get matched results...

Comment: settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

Answer (score 1):

My xpath is a bit rusty. But I am sure that you can make a better xpath than the one I presented below. A better xpath would only select the nodes that has 3 or more of a node that is of type bibr and contains rid that starts with ref. Any who. Here is my solution for getting the nodes you want.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("article.xml");

    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//xref[@ref-type='bibr' and starts-with(@rid,'ref')]/parent::*");

    foreach(XmlNode x in nodes)
    {
        XmlNodeList temp = x.SelectNodes("//xref[@ref-type='bibr' and starts-with(@rid,'ref')]");
        //we only select those that have 3 or more references.
        if (temp.Count >= 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.InnerText);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

**EDIT**
I played around a bit and the code below has an updated xpath which should get everything you want.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("article.xml");

    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*[count(xref[@ref-type='bibr' and starts-with(@rid,'ref')])>2]");

    foreach(XmlNode x in nodes){
        Console.WriteLine(x.InnerText);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: I want the output to be like `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref2">[2]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref3">[3]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref4">[4]</xref>` and `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="rid6">8</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="rid6">9</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="rid10">10</xref>`  Your code is just giving the contents of the `<p>` nodes in the file.

Comment: My code gives the the <p> that has 3 or more children. But no worries. I will modify the code. Give  me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions aren't really good for hierarchical syntaxes. I would write C# code to read the XML and track the number of consecutive xref nodes separated only by ", " or " ".

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     using (var xmlStream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApp1.XMLFile1.xml"))
     {
        int state = 0; // 0 = Look for xref; 1 = look for separator
        string[] simpleSeparators = { " ", ", " };
        string rid = "0";
        StringBuilder nodeText = new StringBuilder();
        string[] consecutiveNodes = new string[3];

        System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings settings = new System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = System.Xml.DtdProcessing.Ignore;
        using (var reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(xmlStream, settings))
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
              if (reader.IsStartElement("xref"))
              {
                 nodeText.Append("<xref");
                 if (reader.HasAttributes)
                 {
                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                       nodeText.AppendFormat(" {0}=\"{1}\"", reader.Name, reader.Value);
                 }
                 nodeText.Append(">");
                 string nextRid = reader.GetAttribute("rid");
                 switch (state)
                 {
                    case 0:
                       break;
                    case 2:
                    case 4:
                       if (Math.Abs(GetIndex(nextRid) - GetIndex(rid)) > 1)
                          state = 0;
                       break;
                 }
                 state++;
                 rid = nextRid;
              }
              else if (reader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
              {
                 if (state > 0)
                    nodeText.Append(reader.Value);
                 if ((state % 2 == 1) && simpleSeparators.Contains(reader.Value))
                       state++;
              }
              else if ((reader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement) && (state > 0))
              {
                 nodeText.AppendFormat("</{0}>", reader.Name);
                 consecutiveNodes[state / 2] = nodeText.ToString();
                 nodeText.Clear();
                 if (state > 3)
                 {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", consecutiveNodes[0], consecutiveNodes[1], consecutiveNodes[2]);
                    state = 0;
                 }
              }
              else if (reader.IsStartElement())
              {
                 nodeText.Clear();
                 state = 0;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }

  static int GetIndex(string rid)
  {
     int start = rid.Length;
     while ((start > 0) && Char.IsDigit(rid, --start)) ;

     start++;
     if (start < rid.Length)
        return int.Parse(rid.Substring(start));
     return 0;
  }
```

This code running on your sample data outputs:

```
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref2">[2]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref3">[3]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref4">[4]</xref>
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="rid6">6</xref><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="rid6">9</xref><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="rid6">10</xref>
```

I updated the code to exclude:

```
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref8">[8]</xref>
```

because ref11, ref13 and ref8 are not consecutive id's as requested in your question.

Comment: I want the output to be like `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref2">[2]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref3">[3]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref4">[4]</xref>`,  `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="rid6">8</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="rid6">9</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="rid10">10</xref>`

Comment: I want to run this program in a collection of xml files and I simply want to search those expressions in the file and then modify it..

Comment: NO.. the file could have same rid values as it is a link node and the main node looks like `<ref id="ref3">` and a file could have same links in multiple locations..Do you get it now?

Comment: Wouldn't LINQ2XML be a better choise for the problem?

Comment: @Don_B I think the updated code does what you requested.

Comment: @Bumba I prefer to optimize performance, and I think this performs better than a solution that loads the whole XML document into memory and performs extra procesing for XPath querying and structuring the document .

Comment: @BlueMonkMN where do you put the xml file? I have it in a location in my D: drive, something like D:\Test\test.xml

Comment: @Don_B In my test program, I just included the XML file as an embedded resource in the EXE file. I assume you already know how to read files so I would recommend replacing the code that opens the stream with your own, depending on where you want to get the XML content from.